# convert XML end time into a timer

Tags: c#, xml

i have extracted an Date / Time (endTime) from this XML file;

```
<row endTime="2015-10-23 21:22:23"
     startTime="2015-10-22 07:44:31"
     endSP="90510" 
     startSP="16000" 
     level="4" 
     typeID="12366"
     queuePosition="0"/>
```

how do i turn this into a count down timer of the time left?

an exmaple if the end time was 2015-10-23 13:00 - i would want it to be (as of right now) 17mins 38seconds remaining

**Edited (added Full code)

```
private void ListViewTrainingQue()
{
    listView1.View = View.Details;
    listView1.GridLines = true;
    listView1.FullRowSelect = true;

    string string2 = "https://api.eveonline.com/char/SkillQueue.xml.aspx?keyID=4602486&&vCODE=BHGVeXQkRLKLkIkZQHdeyUxmUz9EfUwbvGzoc2eO4ZR8kRMYxk8PbD4LMwLF7BvH";

    // Add Columns to listview 
    listView1.Columns.Add("Name", 108);
    listView1.Columns.Add("Level", 100);
    listView1.Columns.Add("Time till completion", 100);
    listView1.Columns.Add("Bar", 100);

    // Create Array to return values to. 
    string[] arr = new string[4];
    ListViewItem item;

   XmlDocument XMLtrans = new XmlDocument();
   XMLtrans.Load(string2);
   XmlNodeList TRnodelist = XMLtrans.SelectNodes("/eveapi/result/rowset/row");
    foreach (XmlNode xmlnode in TRnodelist)
    {

        string array = xmlnode.Attributes["endTime"].InnerText; 

        var date = DateTime.Parse(array);
        var Timespan = date - DateTime.Now;

        if (xmlnode.Attributes["typeID"] != null)
            arr[0] =  xmlnode.Attributes["typeID"].InnerText;
        if (xmlnode.Attributes["level"] != null)
             arr[1] = xmlnode.Attributes["level"].InnerText;
        if (xmlnode.Attributes["endTime"] != null)
            arr[2] = Timespan.ToString();

        item = new ListViewItem(arr);
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

this is what im getting when running it.

[image]

Comment: What kind of error you have with your current code? Also we need to see your current code to help you fix that error.

Comment: ok check edited post, added my full code.

Comment: So do you want the output to be the time left from now (the time of execution) to the endTime?

Comment: yes, thats exactly what i want it to do.

Comment: @Losec where do you have problem with this code? I don't see where you are calculating time left

Comment: i removed the code i was trying to enter, it fell over and i see now that i was going about it all wrong.

Comment: WinForms - all the way

Comment: nah, i just started using this type of code and this is just what i chose at the time. no real reason

Comment: @FarhanAnam you really think that project technology selection is matter of love/hate?

Comment: @Losec parse your date with `var date = DateTime.Parse(dateString);` and then just subscract current date from it `TimeSpan duration = date - DateTime.Now;`

Comment: Check my Edited Post up top

Comment: not working as i expected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken your problem is just about formatting the time as you can already get the difference. So to format it as minutes and seconds (i.e 17mins 38seconds in your example) you can use TimeSpan's Hours, Minutes and Seconds properties. For instance the following code block

```
string array = "2015-10-23 13:00"; 
var date = DateTime.Parse(array);
var Timespan = date - DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(Timespan.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} hours {1} minutes {2} seconds", Timespan.Hours, Timespan.Minutes, Timespan.Seconds));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} minutes {1} seconds", (int)Timespan.TotalMinutes, Timespan.Seconds));
```

would outout this:

```
20:20:24
20 hours 20 minutes 24 seconds
1220 minutes 24 seconds
```

You can choose whichever format you like and play around with the properties to change it.

**UPDATE:**

So in your case if you want to display hours/minutes/seconds for example you can use this:

```
if (xmlnode.Attributes["endTime"] != null)
    arr[2] = string.Format("{0} hours {1} minutes {2} seconds", Timespan.Hours, Timespan.Minutes, Timespan.Seconds);
```

Comment: Hi Hi, thanks for the answer but im lost on where i need to enter this because it's not formatting like you said :) im using Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} hours {1} minutes {2} seconds", Timespan.Hours, Timespan.Minutes, Timespan.Seconds));

Comment: @Losec: Sorry about the confusion. I just posted a console sample to show the formatting options. I've updated my answer.

Comment: my god when code works first time it gets me excited. Anyway thanks bud !!

Comment: is there a quick way to then make the top column start counting down?

Comment: @Losec: Not that I know of. You have to keep refreshing the content with the new time values.

Comment: thats my next part is Auto-Refresh better get me over to google and start readin!